# NSString unicode subscript

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How can I write create an NSString with subscript numerals? I'm trying to create a string that says X10, with the '10' as a subscript.
I tried to use the unicode numerals @"\u0081" and @"\u0080",but xcode gives an error "invalid universal character". Superscript numerals (@"\u00B3", for example) work fine, but I cant get subscripts to work.

Comment: perhaps you could do what you want to do with NSAttributedString ?

Comment: Wikipedia says subscript numerals are \u208X, not 008X - perhaps that is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for U+2081 and U+2080. (U+0081 and U+0080 are not valid codepoints.)